# How do I make bpy.ops.image.save_as() to use my 'Output' settings

Tags: python, image

When saving texture images, how can I make the bpy.ops.image.save_as() operator to use my 'Output' settings from the 'Output Properties' panel?

[image]

While [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/editors/image/editing.html?utm_source=blender-4.0.2#save-as) it's stated that the image output settings can be configured where the *render output properties* can be.
[image]

These settings are have also no effect when the image is tried to saved manually

[image]

Everything needs to be set in the 'Blender File View' window from default.

[image]

Is something turned off, or is there a specific reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to save render result

[image]

Settings will be the same as output properties.

- If you want to save generated image, it will be png by default until you will not save it in other format type.
- If you want to save opened file it will be the same format by default

Comment: Oh so the output panel is only for render images? And can't a generated image be 'tricked' to also use those output settings?